# In case of Islamic banking what is the technique of adding profits to long-term deposits?

Tags: deposits

As we all know that Islamic Banking avoid interests.

Then, what is the technique of adding profits/returns to short/long-term deposits or any deposit?

Comment: Who said there is any? There's no interest, period. If the bank wants to give something in return it will be a gift, not a promised interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do "**Hibah**" ("gift"): [Hibah on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking#Hibah_.28gift.29)

Basically, *the bank rewards you, with a "gift"*, for the profits that it makes from your deposits but without specifying those details in contract.

So, unlike a non-islamic deposit you *can't have any garantee* about when or how much the reward will be.

In that way it's more like a dividend.